Converting ServerHttpRequest to HttpServletRequest
I'm migrating an application from Netflix/Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway:
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    ServletServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest)exchange.getRequest();
    ServletServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse = (ServletServerHttpResponse)exchange.getResponse();
    if (shouldFilter(exchange)) {
        try {
            log.debug("Invoking authorization interceptor");
            if (!checkRequest(
                    serverHttpRequest.getServletRequest(),
                    serverHttpResponse.getServletResponse(),
                    null)) {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Invalid request"));
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, exception);
            return Mono.error(exception);
        }
    }
    return Mono.empty();
}

The test case I wrote is as follows:
private GatewayFilterChain filterChain
private static ServerWebExchange exchange;

def setup() {
    exchange = mock(ServerWebExchange.class)
    ServerHttpRequest request = mock(ServerHttpRequest.class)
    ServerHttpResponse response = mock(ServerHttpResponse.class)
    filterChain = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class)
    when(filterChain.filter(exchange)).thenReturn(Mono.empty())
    when(exchange.getRequest()).thenReturn(request)
    when(exchange.getResponse()).thenReturn(response)
}

However, when testing, I'm getting the following error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest$MockitoMock$6YiKyP1Z cannot be cast to class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest (org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest$MockitoMock$6YiKyP1Z and org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I do have to stick with HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in jakarta, otherwise would be a nightmare to re-implement the downstream service. What would be the best way to cast/convert ServerHttpRequest to HttpServletRequest?

THe problem is your test code, you are mocking the interface but in the actual filter expect a specific class for the request/response. Either mock the class not the interface or programm to interfaces instead of concrete classes. However you are probably better of by implementing a checkRequest which uses the ServerHttpRequest and ServerHttpResponse to validate instead of the underlying request/response.

@M.Deinum could you please give an example? However, convert checkRequest to ServerHttpRequest and ServerHttpResponse is not feasible, since it will require a large code re-write

Where do I state you need a re-write, I suggest adding a method which does the same but for different interfaces. They probably extract information from the request and do some validation. You can have the validation common, and the extracting of the information specific. I nowhere stated you to write the full method. Anyway as stated you are casting to ServletServerHttpResponse but are mocking ServerHttpRequest so the cast will fail. Either mock the class or program to interfaces instead.

@M.Deinum could you write an answer with the appropriate mocking?

Webflux is not compatible with servlets and you cannot cast them

The problem is that you mock the request and response to be ServerHttpRequest and ServerHttpResponse respectively, and you cannot cast those to ServletServerHttpRequest and ServletServerHttpResponse.
In your code you want ServletServerHttpRequest and ServletServerHttpResponse, and extract their HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. You don't need to mock the classes, but instead mock the interfaces:
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class)
ServletServerHttpRequest request = new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest)
HttpServletResponse servletResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class)
ServletServerHttpResponse response = new ServletServerHttpResponse(servletResponse)

// keep these as-is:
when(exchange.getRequest()).thenReturn(request)
when(exchange.getResponse()).thenReturn(response)

You can then configure the servletRequest and servletResponse mocks as needed. The request and response instances don't need any mocking anymore, these delegate to the mocked servletRequest and servletResponse.
